# How to make an if else condition within a while loop in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, loops, if-statement

I want to make an array that looks like this:

```
qqq = [[a,b],[c,d]];
```

But with the code that I got it makes an output that looks like this:

```
qqq= [[a,b],[c,d],];
```

**what should i do to exclude the extra semicolon?**

```
var qqq = [<?php 
        $aw = "select * from city;";
        $wa = mysql_query($aw);

    while($aa = mysql_fetch_array($wa))
        {       
            $cc = $aa['Coordinate_id'];
            $bb = $aa['city_name'];

            echo "[$cc,$bb],";

        }   
?> ];
```

Comment: obligatory please use PDO or mysqli functions, since the mysql functions are depricated

Answer (score 3):

Since you are going for a JSON encoded array, please use the following snippet to achieve exactly the same:

```
var qqq = <?php 
    $aw = "select * from city;";
    $wa = mysql_query($get_marker);

    $arr = array();
    while($aa = mysql_fetch_array($wa)) {
        $arr[] = array($aa['Coordinate_id'], $aa['city_name']);
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>;
```

Comment: Using the `_fetchAll()` functions of PDO or mysqli you can even ommit the loop.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yep... Hence the comment on the question to use PDO or mysqli =)

Comment: it only outputs the last data :(

Comment: @vamkodz Small coding error... Updated the answer with the correct one =)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
while($aa = mysql_fetch_array($wa))
{
    $cc = $aa['Coordinate_id'];
    $bb = $aa['city_name'];
    echo "[$cc,$bb],";
}
```

to this:

```
$result = '';
while($aa = mysql_fetch_array($wa))
{
    $cc = $aa['Coordinate_id'];
    $bb = $aa['city_name'];
    result.="[$cc,$bb],";
} 
echo trim($result,',');
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? can you post an error you have after this change?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echo you should use implode like this

```
<?php 
$aw = "select * from city;";
$wa = mysql_query($get_marker);
$arr = [];
while($aa = mysql_fetch_array($wa))
{       
    $cc = $aa['Coordinate_id'];
    $bb = $aa['city_name'];

    $arr[] = "[$cc,$bb]";
}   
?>

var qqq = [<?php echo implode(',',$arr)?>];
```

I think this improves readability as well and is more easily ported to something more manageable

Comment: does not output anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of rows:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($aw);
```

And check if the condition applies that the last loop is occurring by using a counter:

```
$i = 0;
while($aa = mysql_fetch_array($wa))
{       
    $cc = $aa['Coordinate_id'];
    $bb = $aa['city_name'];

    if ($i < $num)
    {
        echo "[$cc,$bb],";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "[$cc,$bb]";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Finally, note that mysql_* functions are deprecated and should be avoided. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: @vamkodz Can you demonstrate what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead of echo and implode outside while loop

```
var qqq = [<?php 
    $aw = "select * from city;";
    $wa = mysql_query($get_marker);

$ret = array();

while($aa = mysql_fetch_array($wa))
{       
    $cc = $aa['Coordinate_id'];
    $bb = $aa['city_name'];

    $ret[] = "[$cc,$bb]";

}   

echo implode(',', $ret);
?> ];
```